# coredata deleteAllObjects is there a faster way

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Before I go to write my data to my coredata I call

```
[self deleteAllObjects:@"MyEntity"];
```

But this seems to iterate through every single object and delete them which seems abit slow. I was wondering if there is a better / quicker way of doing this.

I have checked out the coredata notes on the developer site.. but thats the only function I can find for deleting entries out of your entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iterating is expensive, there are quicker ways. You can check these answers that have been discussed on SO before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077810/delete-reset-all-entries-in-core-data), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266084/how-to-remove-all-objects-from-core-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383598/core-data-quickest-way-to-delete-all-instances-of-an-entity).